# React native Navigator error: "Cannot configure scene at index 0"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an error message in React native when using the Navigator component:

```
Cannot configure scene at index 0
React.createClass._transitionTo
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out - this can happen if you're making a scene transition and Navigator's `configureScene` prop doesn't return a transition type (e.g. `Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight`).